# breeze manager return promise before success call back completes

Tags: knockout.js

I'm getting stuck with a serious issue in binding knockout observableArray from a breeze call.

Posting my code here...

```
function objCart(object_id,
             brand_name, model_name,
             size, name, imagepath,
             brand_imagepath, model_imagepath,
             quantity, offerAmount, showCartProductImage) {

    this.object_id = ko.observable(object_id);
    this.brand_name = ko.observable(brand_name);
    this.model_name = ko.observable(model_name);
    this.size = ko.observable(size);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.imagepath = ko.observable(imagepath);
    this.brand_imagepath = ko.observable(brand_imagepath);
    this.model_imagepath = ko.observable(model_imagepath);
    this.quantity = ko.observable(quantity);
    this.offerAmount = ko.observable(offerAmount);
    this.showCartProductImage = ko.observable(showCartProductImage);
    this.editEnable = ko.observable(false);
    this.showEdit = ko.observable(true);
    this.showCancel = ko.observable(false);
    this.cancelEdit = ko.observable(false);
    this.offerEdit = function () {
        if (!this.editEnable()) {
            this.editEnable(true);
            this.showCancel(true);
            this.showEdit(false);
            gCartEditQuantity = this.quantity();
            gCartEditOfferAmount = this.offerAmount();
        }
    }
    this.CancelEdit = function () {

        this.editEnable(false);
        this.showEdit(true);
        this.showCancel(false);
        this.quantity(gCartEditQuantity);
        this.offerAmount(gCartEditOfferAmount);

    }

    this.offerUpdate = function () {

        this.editEnable(false);
        this.showEdit(true);
        this.showCancel(false);         
        UpdateCart(this.object_id, this.quantity, this.offerAmount, vm.customerId);

    }

    this.offerDelete = function () {
        DeleteCart(this.object_id, this.quantity, this.offerAmount, vm.customerId);
        // cartItems.remove(this);
    }


    this.ShowItemDetailsModal = function () {

        getItemDetails(this.object_id);
        modaldialog.show(detailsView).then(function () {
            //logger.log('Modal Closed', null, 'home', true);
        });

    }


    this.ShowBrandDetailsModal = function () {

        getBrandDetails(this.object_id);
        modaldialog.show(brandDetails).then(function () {
            //logger.log('Modal Closed', null, 'home', true);
        });

    }

}
```

Making a server call as follows to get the data...

```
function getCartItems(customerId) {

    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.
            from("getCart")
            .withParameters({ CustomerId: customerId
            })
            .orderBy("name");
    var promise = manager
        .executeQuery(query)
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);

    function querySucceeded(data) {

        vm.cartItems([]);
        var temp = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            var crt = new objCart(data.results[i].object_id,
                               data.results[i].brand_name,
                               data.results[i].model_name,
                               data.results[i].size,
                               data.results[i].name,
                               data.results[i].imagepath,
                               data.results[i].brand_imagepath,
                               data.results[i].model_imagepath,
                               data.results[i].quantity,
                               data.results[i].offerAmount,
                               data.results[i].showCartProductImage);
            temp.push(crt);


        }

        vm.cartItems(temp);
        vm.cartItems.valueHasMutated();
        if (vm.cartItems().length > 0) {

            itemsInCart(true);
            checkoutDisplay(true);
        }
        else {

            itemsInCart(false);
            checkoutDisplay(false);
        }

    }

    function queryFailed(error) {
        toastr.error("Query failed: " + error.message);
    }

    return promise;
};
```

Problem is -- when the view is loaded first time, the list shows nothing, even though there is items in cartItems();

for subsequent routernavigates, it shows list with items in viewmodel in the previous call

I think the problem is because the breeze manager returns the promize before the success call back maps the entity.

But I couldn't find a better way to solve it.

Appreciate your feedback and suggessions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a great answer, but maybe a thought to solve it. I hope someone has the answer, because I am in need for it as well.

I ran into the same issue where the promise returns before the data bound to the observable. The only "work around" I could come up with is using JQuery in the Data Access Layer, to bind or do what ever I need to do, after the data is bound to the observable. 
This is horrible design and goes against every code separation, but I simply could not find another way to make it work.

In this example, I had to call a change function after the data was bound.

The code looks like this:

Call in VM:

```
datacontext.getProduct(productObservable, productSearch.Id());
```

Data Access Layer (datacontext):

```
function getProduct(productObservable, id) {
        query = "Product/Get/" + id;

        $('#loading-indicator').show();
        return newPricingEm().executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed)

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            $('#loading-indicator').hide();
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data.results[0], {}, productObservable);
            // Should not be in here
            $('#productCategory').change();
            log("Retrieved [Product] from remote data source",
                data, true);
        }
    }
```

Attention to:

```
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data.results[0], {}, productObservable);
        // Should not be in here
        $('#productCategory').change();
```

The **$('#productCategory').change();** is firing the event I needed to fire after the data was bound.

So in your case you could use JQuery to bind the observable to your View in this step.

Again, this is pretty bad design, but I wasn't able to find any other solution at this point.

Hope that helps you to get it at least to work.